# Git diff to wiki markup with colors preserved

Tags: git, confluence, wiki-markup

Is there a way to export

```
git diff --color <commitA> <commitB>
```

to wiki-markup (to be used in confluence) **with** colors.

Comment: There are millions scripts to [convert ansi to html](https://encrypted.google.com/search?q=convert+ansi+to+html). [Ansifilter](http://www.andre-simon.de/doku/ansifilter/en/ansifilter.php) can convert ANSI codes to text, HTML, pango, TeX, rtf and BBCodes.

Comment: it's about wiki markup and not html